# AlchemyAPI API key not working

Tags: ibm-cloud, alchemyapi

Using a free trial account for AlchemyAPI (Bluemix), the provided API key only works for:

https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/calls/url/URLGetRankedNamedEntities.

But I want to use it for:

https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/text/TextGetRankedNamedEntities.

Do I need to add another key, or do I have to upgrade to a premium account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The call you want to do isn't in the v1 API:

http://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/alchemy-language/api/v1/

---

The documentation containing that call is [here](https://www.alchemyapi.com/api/entity/textc.html#rtext) uses:

**http://access.alchemyapi.com/calls/text/TextGetRankedNamedEntities**

as the endpoint and not the **gateway-a.watsonplatform**.

My API Key from Bluemix still seems to work for this query:

```
curl -i "http://access.alchemyapi.com/calls/text/TextGetRankedNamedEntities?apikey={apikey}&outputMode=json&text=How%20old%20is%20Paris%20Hilton"
```

Comment: The URL is what it shows on my console doc. I think you can also see the URL if you click on 'TEXT', beside 'HTML', and 'URL'.

Comment: I've just opened up a defect for the console doc. Thanks for using Bluemix!